# How to start counting again when for exceeds a certain value?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I have this `for` that generates a series. The main problem is that I only have 9 colors.

```
for (let i = 0; i < dataZCsv.length; i++) {
    let colorNumber = i;
    if (colorNumber > 8) {

    }
    let dataBlok = {
        name: nazvyZCsv[i],
        data: dataZCsv[i],
        visible: jednaStopaTF,
        regression: hodnoty.trendy,
        regressionSettings: {
            type: 'polynomial',
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i --> colorNumber],
            dashStyle: 'ShortDot',
            name: " ",
            hideInLegend: true
        }
    };
    serie.push(dataBlok);
    serie[0].visible = true;
};
```

So even if `i` exceeds 8, it will start writing `i` greater than 8 to the `color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i]` and this is problem. I have only 9 colors. So I need to do that when it exceeds 8, it starts counting again from 0. But `i` still need to use it in other variables (`name: nazvyZCsv[i], data: dataZCsv[i]`), where it must be up to the maximum value (`dataZCsv.length`).

Ideally, I would make a separate variable for the color number `colorNumber`, which when it reaches 8 starts again from 0 to end of `dataZCsv.length`.

Something like:

```
let colorNumber = i;
if (colorNumber > 8) {
    colorNumber = 0;
    colorNumber++;
}
```

or:

```
let colorNumber = i;
if (colorNumber > 8) {
    colorNumber = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < dataZCsv.length - 9; j++) {
        colorNumber + j;
    }
}
```

But this not work in `for`

I've been stuck for several hours and I still don't see a solution. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Use the [remainder (or modulo) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder), like `[i % 9]`

Comment: I am stupid. It is such a simple solution and I am looking for complexity. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use colors[i % 9] where 9 is the number of colors

Answer (score 2):

You could take the remainder of the index with the length of the colors array ([reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder)).

```
let colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
```

later in the object

```
color: colors[i % colors.length]
```

You need to separate to get an array and to get a value, if you could get an arbitrary count of colors which maybe not known in advance.